# styling each line inside pre with css

Tags: html, css

i have html code

```
<pre>
line 1
line 2
line 3
</pre>
```

how can i put some css style to the "lines" inside `<pre>`, without adding other wrapper into it?

what i mean is something like

```
pre lines{ color: red}
```

i'm having difficulties on finding the css selector for that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "lines" exactly? Why can't you give the color to the pre itself?

Comment: @Pekka: What his mean is give different style on each line

Comment: @Shakti I'm not sure about that - the example isn't clear

Comment: It seems like Lee wants to treat the lines like separate divs or so, for example to color them in zebra stripes or put them in boxes... I don't know any way to do this without inner containers...

Comment: Yeah, if you want to style each line individually, this is not possible in pure HTML/CSS. The container's contents are a text node, it can't be addressed for styling specifically.

Comment: @opatut, yes, that is exactly what i'm up to. it can be easily done using some wrapper, but the problem is, i only have the "pre" (with its content lines) without any wrapper.

Answer (score 18):

You can use this little CSS3 trick, with gradients. This will create automatically, without extra spans, a "zebra" effect:

```
background: #555;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#555 50%, #505050 50%);
background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(#555 50%, #505050 50%);
background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(#555 50%, #505050 50%);
background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(#555 50%, #505050 50%);
background-image:         linear-gradient(#555 50%, #505050 50%);
background-position: 0 0;
background-repeat: repeat;
background-size: 4.5em 4.5em;
```

Try different CSS "line-height" so that the text appears correctly.

see: http://www.dte.web.id/2012/03/css-only-zebra-striped-pre-tag.html#.UUoV6lugkoM

Answer (score 11):

If you want add color to all lines in pre, just add

```
pre {color: red;}
```

But if you want to add color to some lines, you need extra markup:

```
<pre>
<span>Line1</span>
line2
<span>Line3</span>
</pre>

pre span {color: red;}
```